# I want to edit a single post in wordpress but in goes to another

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to edit a post in wordpress but it goes to another post. I don't know how this happened after I optimized it using a optimization plugin. Is there anyone here who encountered this problem? How do you resolve this?

Comment: Where are you getting the edit link from? The admin post list? The WP Admin Bar? The front end single view or archive view?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.